# How to rename an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, rename

I have a list
    `dl[vr]`
where `vr` is an arbitrary name extracted from a file.
what I want is to create an array with the same name as `vr`,
so I wonder besides
    `ar = np.array(dl[vr])`
 what should I do to name the array the same as the variable `vr`?

thanks

Comment: With the same name? Or a different name but the same value?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  You shouldn't be pulling the NAMES for variables from a file, only values.  Could you provide an exact example of what you're looking for?

Comment: But why to change ? It will be hard to use it in rest of script if you don't know how it will be named.

Comment: Is the list `dl`? If `vr` is an arbitrary name extracted from a file why are you indexing with it?

Comment: Not sure what exactly that is. Say vr = "aaa", I want the array name to be "aaa" as well. Sorry for any confusion I'm not a good programmer.

Comment: Is `dl` actually a dictionary?

Comment: `dl` is a list with name `vr`

Comment: @LilMuji: Variable names can't really be set at run time.  You can KIND of do it with a dictionary, but it probably isn't what you're asking for.  I think you need to stop and think about what you're really trying to do.  What purpose is there for naming variables at run-time?

Comment: @Sohcahtoa82 The purpose is to extract data from multiple files, each time the "names" of some entries in the file will be something different, so that's why I'm trying to name it with what I found in the files

Comment: I think you're fundamentally confused about what a variable is. You would never want to dynamically name a variable.

Comment: Better use dictionary.

Comment: @WaleedKhan actually I don't even know. I wonder if a list or array consist more information than just the elements inside it. Can I give it a "name" to be refer to as an explanation of what the list/array really is?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I guess you're right

Comment: But how do you use this variable in rest of script if it can be `aaa` or `hello_world` or `today_is_first_july` or everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you're asking for, but it sounds like you want an arbitrary string from a file used to identify an array (presumably filled with data from that same file).

Rather than trying to give the variable itself that arbitrary name, I think you would be better off storing the array in a dictionary and using the arbitrary name as the key:

```
arrayDict = {}
name = readStringFromFile()
data = readArrayFromFile()
arrayDict[name] = data
```

Obviously, you should choose more appropriate names for these variables if you can :)

You *could* create a new variable with an unknown name, but then you would have to access it indirectly as well.  You might as well make this more obvious with your own dictionary.

Comment: May I ask what's the difference between this `arrayDict[name]` and the original array itself (`data`) when I further operate the array?  which one should I choose? thx

Comment: There's not really any difference, but I assumed you wanted to associate the data with a particular label, so it could be retrieved later and identified by that label.  This would be especially useful if you were going to load multiple files and process them afterwards.  If you only have one array, and will be using it immediately, there's no benefit to doing this - just use the array immediately and choose a descriptive name that works for all situations.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are totally confused with basics.

```
listA = ['A','C','1']
```

here `listA` is a `list`

```
dictA = {}
dictA["name"] = "xxxxxxx"
```

here `dictA` is a `dict`

Following links will help you to understand what is list(array)/dict :

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict
- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `globals()` or `locals()`

```
globals()['aaa'] = 'hello world'

print aaa

'hello world'
```

But in my opinion better use dictionary.